# Распаковка шрифта из ресурсов проекта VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Не могу никак разобраться, в чем проблема. Почему не работает?

Файл со шрифтом находится в проекте как внедренный ресурс.
Пытался сначала сделать через `FileCopy`, но после распаковки в папку Temp для копирования файла, говорит, что файл уже занят и ничем помочь не может.

Второй вариант - это пытаюсь распаковать файл шрифта (ttf) напрямую в папку C:\Windows\Fonts - но и это не работает. На рабочий стол (проверил), шрифт кидает и распаковывает, а в папку Fonts - нет.

Помогите разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы внедренный файл (ttf) в проект VS 2017 можно было напрямую установить в папку Windows\Fonts?

Мой код:

```
void ExtractResource(string resource, string path)
{
    Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
}

private void FontCopy()
{
    string fontsfolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
    string exePath = fontsfolder + @"\a_Futurica_ExtraBold.ttf";
    ExtractResource("RustCheatCheck.a_Futurica_ExtraBold.ttf", exePath);
    /*if (!File.Exists(exePath))
    {
        ExtractResource("RustCheatCheck.a_Futurica_ExtraBold.ttf", exePath);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Обычному пользователю (приложению, запущенному из-под обычного пользователя) запрещён доступ в системные папки. Поэтому либо инсталлятор вашего приложения должен ставить шрифты в такие папки, либо извлекайте шрифт в рабочие папки.

Comment: Программа запускается от имени администратора.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код для распаковки ресурсов правильный.

Но Windows, как уважающая себя операционная система, не даёт приложениям, запущенным с правами юзера, модифицировать системный каталог (а то любая программа сможет внести хаос в систему). Чтобы писать в системный каталог, программе нужны права администратора.

---

Кроме того, копирование шрифта в каталог Fonts недостаточно для того, чтобы шрифт начал работать, его нужно ещё зарегистрировать в системе. Но это не лучшая опция — если пользователь снесёт ваше приложение, удалите ли вы за собой ненужные шрифты?

Если вы пишете на WPF, вы можете просто использовать шрифты не распаковывая их, прямо из ресурсов. Для этого включите шрифт в проект как Resource (не Embedded Resource!), и ссылайтесь на него по внутреннему пути:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="fonts/#Имя Вашего Шрифта"/>
```

Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications

Если вы пользуетесь Winforms, оставайтесь на Embedded Resource, и используйте `PrivateFontCollection`:

```
static void AddFontFromResource(PrivateFontCollection collection, string resouce)
{
    Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    var memory = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontBytes.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, memory, bytes.Length);
    collection.AddMemoryFont(memory, bytes.Length);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontData);
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23658552/276994

---

У Windows, судя по всему, нету документированного способа добавлять системные шрифты программным путём. В сети есть различные обходные пути, которые могут перестать работать в следующей версии. Поэтому использование локального шрифта кажется правильным подходом. В частности, [`AddFontResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326(v=vs.85).aspx) добавляет шрифт только на текущую сессию, до перезагрузки.

Возможно, вам нужен инсталлятор, как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14231436/276994).

Comment: Программа и запускается от имени администратора :)

Comment: @Xhonor: А что выдаёт `cacls C:\Windows\Fonts`?